# node forever command shows nothing

Tags: node.js, forever

I input "forever list" in centOS command line, but it shows nothing after Enter. (BTW, the node process really exists.)
Just as the pic below:

[image: wrong]

what I want:

[image: correct]

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Use text as much as possible instead of including screenshots.

Comment: _"The node process really exists."_ Prove it.

Comment: @TGrif My xxx.js listens 8082 port. Before I run "forever start xxx.js", I run "netstat -apn|grep 8082", and there's nothing. Then I run "forever start xxx.js", the command doesn't return to "[username@machine /]$", but stays in "forever start xxx.js", just like it is still running. Finally, I make "ctrl + C" to stop it ,and run"netstat -apn|grep 8082", the node is listening to 8082 port.